# Dynamically creating content on custom URL without getting 404

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, 404-error

My goal is to have this link structure:

mypage.com/item/subitem/code

Code are 6 random letters and numbers.

I tried with having category and subcategory, but I dislike that because then i have to create post for every code that i have, and there are lots of it.

What I want to is to have a template for page item/subitem/code and just take code as query (similar to ?code) but I cannot change this structure since it's about qr codes and they cannot be changed.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it´s totally possible, I just did that for a similar project some weeks ago.

I found this very helpful: [How to pass extra variables in URL with Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586835/how-to-pass-extra-variables-in-url-with-wordpress)

Basically the process is the following: Register new `query_vars`, fill them with life, pass them to a specific template which looks for them and then do whatever you like.

I did an integration for a REST-based web service with that. Live querying the information from the service, based on the ID I pass like this: `mysite.com/events/1567612313/`

Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what why you want this, but this will create much more headaches than solving them.

Lets look at a few things here, you need pages.

- For this you can have one template, not a problem.
- Hierarchical post types are expensive and will crash your backend when you start running into only a very few thousand of pages
- 6 random numbers gives you millions of possibilities, so if one million visitors visit your site with one milllion random numbers, you are going to create one million pages. This will most certainly crash your site.

  Even if you are going to make use of non hierarchical post type like `post` and assign terms to it to create your desired structure, you are going to run into issues like very slow page loads or even a fatal error due to time limits exceeded
- How are you going to decide what content to generate and save for a specific page load. What will the difference in context be between page  `item/subitem/000001` and  `item/subitem/500000`.

To add to the issues above you will need to figure out the following:

- How you are going to determine if a page will 404. A 404 is only generated when the main query is done running its SQL query and the queried page is not found. Only then is a 404 page header returned.
- I'm really not sure if this is really possible without messing around with other stuff or even really possible at all, but you would need to somehow intercept the main query before it runs so that you can check if the specific queried page exists, and if not, create the page, and then run the main query.

In short, I cannot see how this can work without any issues. It just seems like a really bad design flaw, but as I said, I do not know why you really need to do this